# Upload a file to S3

Tags: file-upload

I want to upload the file to s3. If I provide the aws key and secret key as hidden field in the form will there be any security issues?
Is it safe to provide the keys in the form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

An attacker can click View Source and steal your keys.

Comment: Can enctype tag in html form be application/pdf?
i want to post pdf file do i need to take care of encrypting it or browser will do it automatically for pdf.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean? You want a file upload?